# Create local TCP connection from C program in Ubuntu VM to Labview in Windows (Host)

Tags: windows-7, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, tcp

Sorry if this is lengthy, I'll try to keep it as concise as possible. I have made a C program which runs in Ubuntu in a virtual machine and a Labview program running in windows (the host of the VM) that can send and receive data through a TCP connection. I use the Bridged Network setting in virtualbox and currently have to provide Labview with the IP of the VM and Port number used by the C program.

I noticed that if I turn off my internet in windows, the data cannot be transferred and the TCP connection is not established between Labview in windows host and the C program in the VM. Is there a way to have this connection work locally, ie. even if I am not connected to the internet, the TCP connection can still be made and data sent as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of bridged mode, use either host-only networking or NAT networking mode. NAT lets the VM use the Internet via the host machine, while host-only does not.

Comment: Hi, I might have been unclear, I want the connection/data stream to exist without any internet connection on both sides (VM and host)

Comment: Yes, both host-only and NAT modes accomplish just that. You have a virtual network card on the host that is up regardless of the state of any real physical network.

Comment: Alright awesome, unfortunately I can't seem to get that working do I need to forward a port or something, when I enter the IP that VM tells me Ubuntu is using the Labview program no longer connects. The IP used to look like 192.169.x.xx now it is 10.0.2.15. Am I using the wrong IP

Comment: Check what the IP of the host is using e.g., ipconfig .

Comment: I did, what should I do with it? I tried them in Labview and that doesn't work. Thanks for helping out by the way, I really appreciate it

Comment: Nevermind, I think I've got it working, I changed to Host only instead of NAT, and the IP came up in the VM. Thanks a lot!